# Creating a System of Equations given the roots of the equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, education

Say I was given three **roots** of a $3$ variable system, where $x=3, y=2, z=-8$.

I was then instructed to create a three equation / three variable system of equations from those roots (edited).

How can that be done?

Comment: What is wrong with $x=2,y=3,z=-8?$

Comment: To elaborate/reiterate, $$\begin{cases}x = 2\\y=3\\z=-8\end{cases}$$ is a perfectly valid system of equations in three variables.

Answer (score 0):

The comment of Ross Millikan gives a very simple and direct answer, if you want a more interesting system of equations just put any random coefficients to $x$, $y$ and $z$:

$3x-y+2z = a$

$5x-y-3z = b$

$x+y+z = c$

and calculate $a$, $b$ and $c$ replacing $x=2$, $y=3$ and $z=-8$.

This will give you a system that has that solution BUT it may have more solutions, depending of the coefficients one choose.